# Switch between iframes with a different interval between them

Tags: html, iframe

I have this script below. It works fine. But I want to be able to set a specific interval for iframe A, another one for iframe B and another one for iframe C. Why? **For example:** Because I have a 10 sec presentation on the first one, a 10 min presentation on the second and a 15 sec presentation on the third.

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="http://gemus.novohamburgo.rs.gov.br" 
frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script>
var urls = [
'http://www.gmail.com',
'http://saude.novohamburgo.rs.gov.br',
'http://www.yahoo.com',
];

setInterval(function() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);
    document.getElementById('myiframe').src = urls[rand];
}, 15000);
</script>

<style>
iframe {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 1080px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is it live demo:

I made small class (nice for data structure)

ROOT.urls and ROOT.intervals must have same length .

**Fixed Code Snippet**

```html
<script>


function CLASS_SWITCHING_IFRAME () {

     var ROOT = this;

     ROOT.urls = [
    
     'https://maximumroulette.com', 
     'https://saude.novohamburgo.rs.gov.br',
 
     ];

     ROOT.intervals = [
     8000,
     8000
     ];

     ROOT.current = 0;

     }


     var MAKEINSTANCE = new CLASS_SWITCHING_IFRAME();



  function CALL_ME () {

    var TIMER_INSTANCE = setTimeout(function(){

    MAKEINSTANCE.current++;
    if ( typeof MAKEINSTANCE.urls[MAKEINSTANCE.current] != 'undefined' ) {

    document.getElementById('myiframe').src = MAKEINSTANCE.urls[MAKEINSTANCE.current];

    }
    else 
    {
     
    MAKEINSTANCE.current = -1;

       }
                 
     
      CALL_ME()

    } , MAKEINSTANCE.intervals[MAKEINSTANCE.current] );
    
    

   }
   
   
   CALL_ME();
</script>

<iframe id="myiframe" src="https://maximumroulette.com" style="background:black;" />
```

Comment: It's not switch iframes on your example. The iframe is always the same. Can you fix it please?

Comment: I already use one iframe , you will only need to add random logic.